# I need help understanding how I should use AWS with a GraphQL server and Apollo client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node.js/GraphQL server that I created and deployed to elastic beanstalk. On the client, I have a react app with Apollo. The problem is, I am hard coding the URL from the elastic beanstalk app into apollo client. What is the protocol for securing this URL so that no one else can see it? Should I even be concerned about that? I've looked at other services such as Amplify and AppSync. Also, I've seen people using API Gateway. I'm not really sure what I should be looking at to get the right answer. I should clarify that the client will not be hosted on AWS just the node.js server.

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of the following:

1) Place the IP address in a file outside of version control (.gitignore) and import that into your app.

2) You could use environment variables.

You can define the variables in your app like the following...

```
const SomeRandomVariable = process.env.GRAPHQL_IP;
```

Now, when you go to build your app, you can do the following:

```
REACT_APP_MY_VAR=10.20.123.456 npm start
```

*Note: If you are on React Native, use react-native-config.*

I hope that helps!

Comment: I considered using an environment variable. The thing is, the app is on IIS and I don't really have access to the server to add the variable to IIS. I guess I was hoping there would be some kind of configuration that I could implement in AWS and then access that configuration or key from within the app.